# Recursion with linked lists for Java student

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Please be gentle on me here... I'm learning and could use some assistance. I'm trying to wrap my head around the linked list method below. I thought I understood how recursion worked, but I'm missing something here. Could someone help me understand the logic, and the complete call stack for this method? I can't figure out how the items are added up... I'm afraid some degree of detail is needed here. I've looked elsewhere for help but other examples do not seem to be helping.

```
/**
* Compute the sum of all the integers in a linked list of integers. 
* @param head a pointer to the first node in the linked list
*/
  public static int addItemsInList( IntNode head ) { 
    if ( head == null ) {
        // Base case: The list is empty, so the sum is zero. 
      return 0;
    } else {
          // Recursive case: The list is non-empty. Find the sum of
          // the tail list, and add that to the item in the head node.
          // (Note that this case could be written simply as
          //return head.item + addItemsInList( head.next );)
      int listsum = head.item;
      int tailsum = addItemsInList( head.next ); 
      listsum = listsum + tailsum;
      return listsum;
   }
}
```

Comment: make a list on paper and work your way through it. This is about the simplest recursion sample I've ever seen.

Comment: Gee, thanks for the help John.

Comment: Did I not explain well enough that I did not understand the logic, and that I was new to this? Anyway, thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comment. The commented code is imho better to understand than introducing 2 temporary variables. The point to get is, that the rest of the List, which follows the head, is in itself a List, and this List is head.next.

```
/**
* Compute the sum of all the integers in a linked list of integers. 
* @param head a pointer to the first node in the linked list
*/
  public static int addItemsInList( IntNode head ) { 
    if ( head == null ) {
        // Base case: The list is empty, so the sum is zero. 
      return 0;
    } else {
        // Recursive case: The list is non-empty. Find the sum of
        // the tail list, and add that to the item in the head node.
      return head.item + addItemsInList (head.next);)
   }
}
```

A List of 4 Ints can be seen like this:

```
List (8, List(7, List (3, List (2, List ()))))
```

The last element being the empty list, which returns 0.

So you have head.item 8, and add to it addItemsInList (7 ...).
There you add 7 and add from 3... from 2 ... .

In the end, the empty List returns 0, 2+0 = 2, returns to the previous call, which adds 3+2 and returns 5, where 7 is waiting to return 12, and finally 8 adds 12 and returns 20.